# Start and run CANape from command prompt

Tags: cmd, can-bus, capl, canape

Is it possible to start and run vector canape from the command prompt and/or by using any other external script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just start it by typing `canape32.exe` in your command prompt.

`Syntax: canape32 [Options] [File]`

If a CNA or INI file is entered on the command line, CANape will load that configuration. An A2L or DB file will start CANape in Database Editor mode. All other files are opened as measurement files, if necessary a signal selection dialog opens. But there are a lot of available command line parameters to control all kind of behaviour. Check the canape online help ('Exec\CANAPE01.chm' in your CANape installation directory) section 'Command Line Options' for more details.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried to access CANape through command line but it shows an "ASAP3 Active" window and doesn't open CANape. Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it via COM or their API.  You can use C++, Python, really anything that can thump either interface.  Python seems to be the most popular to use.